# Why have the question descriptions and user info (avatar and badges) been removed for "tagged questions"?

Tags: discussion, new-nav

I noticed today, that the cramped view of the SO main page:

[image]

now also affects the **tagged questions**

[image]

which was not the case before. Though I never cared about the main page, I found the additional information in case of filtering (e.g. for tags), like still available on tex.se:

[image]

very useful! Is there any reason why it got removed? Can we have it back?

The short description (or first few sentences) under each question title give me an additional indicator about whether I should have a look at the question or not. And the cramped design itself appears very unfortunate to me. The view counter is far to dominant, and I'm actually missing the user avatar and the badges.

Now it looks more like a forum to me, than a Q&A site, which makes it less apealing to visit. Is it just me?

I usually quickly scan the newest question of my tag for interesting content, and yes I also look for the users asking, as high-rep with a high badge count usually ask more interesting questions (I know I shouldn't pre-judice, but the lack of time makes it necessary.).

I guess its absolutely subjective - but maybe we can discuss, who liked it more than before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When there were some changes made to the new nav recently, everything was reset.  The view you are looking for is still there, you just need to change the setting.  Look to the top right, next to where the total question count located, and click the right most button.

> [image]

You will get the view you are looking for:

> [image]

Comment: Great, I haven't noticed that button. Thanks for pointing it out!